# when we inherit a class which is having the private members in java.Are the private members also get inherit?

Tags: java, oop

When we inherit a class which is having the private members in Java, are the private members also inherited? If yes, why cant get them by the class object? If no, then why?

Comment: No, the private member are not inherited

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. And study the Oracle Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `private` means that they cannot be accessed directly in a sub-class. Have a look at [Java's access control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: All sub classes have those member even if they are not visible.

Comment: Good point. I've re-worded my answer to be more precise.